# Pub/media css was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff in magento 2

Tags: magento2, css, ubuntu

> I set up Magento 2 localhost migrated from the server.
>
> but when load frontend showing like this

[image]

```
Pub/media CSS was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff in Magento 2
```

how I can fix this

Magento ver 2.2.6

ubuntu 18.04

PHP 7

Answer (score 2):

make sure .htaccess exist in pub/static

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove all files from `var/` folder.
2. Check for .htaccess in pub/static. If not exists, take a file from a fresh setup.
3. Run the following commands

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   ```

Comment: already there and i cleared cache

Comment: but magento backend is working fine

Comment: then flush cache and clear browser history then try in incognito mode

Comment: tried not working

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Same problem I am getting on my localhost so for this I have tried below methods: 
 * `replace .htaccess file in pub/static folder` (no luck)
 * after lot search I run this commands and successfully deployed

```
 sudo chmod -R 777 pub/ var/ app/
 sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 sudo php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
sudo chmod -R 777 pub/ var/ app/
```

After these commands all errors from console gone 
 [image]

Comment: superb let me try

Comment: Deploy mode in production works well... If this perfect then upvote my ans

Comment: Already updated .htaccess from default Magento 2.2.9 and run below command but got error on js files only.

Comment: can you try to change deploy mode again and run same commands, this is only cause of mode changes, also check if you are using multiple language then deploy using 

'php -d -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US th_TH fr_FR'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have .htaccess in pub/static. If you don't have file take a file from a fresh setup.

Then do static content deploy and clear cache.

If It's not working make sure you have enabled mod_rewrite in ubuntu

Comment: mine backend is working fine without any problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The reason was that we added a css file which didn't exist when enabling merging css. Please check your custom js or third party js. We can also check the log.

For example, file doesn't exist.

```
<css src="Vendor_Module::yourcustom.css"/>
```

Comment: i will check .....

Comment: @prabhakaran7 did your issue resolve?

Comment: still i'm not yet checked...

Comment: Is there any method to find error like this? I got this error only in js file

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the steps like

```
rm -rf var/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

and still not worked. (These steps are required but it's incomplete)

You must have to change `.htaccess` file with a new one in `pub/static` **whether exists or not**.

After changing it, I ran `cache:clean` command again, and then it **works well** for me.

Most people might skip this step because .htaccess is already available in pub/static.

You can get `.htaccess` new one in magento official github:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/pub/static/.htaccess

(It's for Magento 2.3, and you can choose your appropriate version in branch)

P.S: If u got **memory exhausted** error while running the commands, try with

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento ...
```