# After static deploy , my website not running properly alignment was changed in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

I want to run the code static deploy for cache problem remove in my website.
But static deploy code compliated successfully, website not working properly, there is a problem in css and design changed collapsed. so, what is the solution for this issue? Please reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are getting Mime type errors in console

Can you try these commands

```
 sudo chmod -R 777 pub/ var/ app/
 sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 sudo php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
sudo chmod -R 777 pub/ var/ app/
```

ref https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/296528/82482

Comment: ok i will try . thanks

Comment: still same issue occured.